# Python "For" loops threading

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

I have to write a Python script that process a big count of files.
I wrote a for loop that run on it, read each file and do some changes on it.
I need to process some files everytime, and think about Threading.

I want plus or minus 20 threads, that each one of them will process one file everytime. 
When the thread releases from his file process, it will get another file (In other words- the For loop will send every file it gets to free thread and continue running).
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you have already?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ThreadPool` you can create a pool of threads and execute a function in each thread. Example:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def _process(filename):
    # do something with filename
    pass

pool = ThreadPool(processes=20)
pool.map(_process, (filename for filename in ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']))
pool.close()
```

`ThreadPool` is undocumented but it's basically the same as `multiprocessing.Pool` but uses threads instead of processes.

Comment: strictly speaking, this will create a pool of *processes* rather than threads; that's probably just fine, though.

Comment: No, `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` creates a pool of threads (as mentioned in my answer), while `multiprocessing.Pool` creates a pool of processes.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination : What if the function does not need any argument? How do I make it use multithreading?

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy you can use `task = pool.apply_async(_process)` and later fetch its result using `task.get()`. If you want to use `pool.map` your function must expect a parameter, you can just add a dummy parameter and use something like `pool.map(_process, range(5))` to run 5 threads calling `_process`.

Comment: how do i wait until all processes are finished?

Comment: `pool.map` will only return when all tasks are complete and returns the result as a list. If you want to run a single task and wait for it then `pool.apply` is what you want, you can also run multiple tasks using `pool.apply_async` and then wait by calling `task.get()` where task is the returned value by `apply_async`.